# What does “over-promoted bath toy” in Hugh Grant’s tweet exactly mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Hugh Grant, British actor called the U.K. Prime Minister, Boris Johnson, an ‘over-promoted rubber bath toy’ in his tweet on August 29, which reads:

> “You will not fuck with my children’s future. You will not destroy the
>   freedom my grandfather fought two world wars to defend. Fuck off
>   you **over-promoted rubber bath toy.** Britain is revolted by you and you
>   little gang of masturbatory prefects.”
>   [Source](https://www.irishtimes.com/life-and-style/people/an-over-promoted-bath-toy-celebrities-slam-boris-johnson-1.4001082)

I first thought the phrase, ‘over-promoted rubber bath toy’ meant immediate Brexit with no conditions attached. But the next day’s ‘insider.com’ annotated the twitter as:

> The actor called the PM an over-promoted rubber bath toy and his cabinet a little gang of masturbatory prefects.

What does ‘over-promoted rubber bath toy’ exactly mean in Hugh Grant’s context?
What does “rubber bath toy” have to do with the new British Prime Minister?

Does ‘over-promoted’ mean “overly advertised / publicized,” or does it mean his “premature ascending" to high position as Prime Minister of a great country?

Comment: *Overpromoted* means “overhyped beyond his intrinsic value”: your first guess. *Bath toy* could either mean an “cartoonish child’s toy of no value except for pretending” (like a rubber duck), an oblique and very British reference to a *dildo* (not really a “bath toy”, but often employed in a bath), which argument is at least weakly bolstered by the “mastrubatory prefects” quip, or a simile between Johnson’s physical looks and a bath toy of some kind. He doesn’t look like any bath toy I know, but maybe they have different bath toys in the UK.

Comment: Oh, it’s the rubber duck thing. There was apparently a notable event when [his opponents protested outside his headquarters with a bunch of rubber ducks](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.indy100.com/article/boris-johnson-hq-2000-rubber-ducks-activisits-no-10-tory-leadership-contest-8977761%3famp). Because he was “ducking” the some issue. Plus rubber duckies are brightly colored, false, and cartoonish?

Comment: Or possibly BoJo reminds of a rubber bath duck!! https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2019/06/27/15/boris-1.jpg

Comment: I didn't read this as being related to dildos.  However, activists have used rubber ducks to make critical statements about Boris Johnson, e.g. *Boris Johnson has been accused of “ducking” questions about his personal life, so activists decided to flood the street of his campaign HQ with rubber ducks,* *Since his leadership launch, Boris Johnson has [been] ducking the British people,* etc.  Also, I recently heard the BBC's "World At One" do a retrospective character overview of Johnson, which featured his mishap falling into a river (when mayor of London) in which, if I remember right, ...

Comment: ... he was described as bobbing in the water like a rubber bath toy. The point they were trying to make, I thought, was that where some might have found the experience humiliating, he didn't mind playing the buffoon.  Also I think he's seen as someone who keeps bobbing back up to the surface like a rubber duck.

Comment: Who but a small child is pleased with a rubber bath toy?  to adults, it is a silly, pointless nuisance. I read this as a dig at his supporters.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to allow for the possibility that "over-promoted" and "rubber bath toy" are not necessarily conjoined.

It seems to me that Grant's use of "over-promoted" is a commentary on the job Johnson now holds—he's in over his head as PM, has been advanced beyond his depth. The "rubber bath toy" is just a simple insult mocking Johnson's puffy appearance and wacko hair.

This makes more sense than trying to apply "over-promoted" to the toy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that in this case *over-promoted* is used in the metaphorical sense of being hyped too far.  I think it means, simply, *elevated in rank above the individual's capabilities*.  History books seem to be littered with soldiers over-promoted to general rank.

For a rubber bath-toy to be elevated to Prime Minister of a great country would *prima facie* be a case of over-promotion.

Answer (score 0):

When I read that (forgetting the rubber duck incident), this image came to mind:

[image]

Which is, of course, a copy of sorts of this image:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't answer the question in the slightest. None of those baby (blimp)  balloons are rubber bath toys that children with at bath time.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - But they seem like "over-promoted rubber bath toys".  Over-inflated, at least.

Comment: They seem exactly like helium-filled balloons, and if you don't explain who the two balloons represent, then why bother posting on an English *language* site? The Trump one is recognizable but the Boris Johnson ballon looks nothing like him, only the £350 sticker on the red double decker gives it away.